# Firestore query using multiple where, orderBy and startAt, endAt

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

So I have a query like this.

```
firestore()
    .collection('posts')
    .where('category', '==', category)
    .orderBy('price', 'asc')
    .startAt(minPrice)
    .endAt(maxPrice)
    .orderBy('title', 'asc')
    .startAt(searchString)
    .endAt(`${searchString}\uf8ff`)
    .limit(10)
    .get()
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res.docs);
      setPosts(res.docs);
    })
```

Where I filter first by category and than I want filter for price in and between min and max price

After that I also want to run this filter

```
.orderBy('title', 'asc')
.startAt(searchString)
.endAt(`${searchString}\uf8ff`)
```

To get the partial string match on title

The query is running without any error but it always return an emply array.
Can anyone help me with this problem.

Comment: "The query is running without any error" => Are you sure about that? Did you try to add a catch block to see if there is an error.

Comment: I'm with Renaud here: since your current code doesn't handle errors, they may well go unnoticed. Add a `catch((e) => console.error(e))` block after the `then` block to see the errors and look specifically for anything about a missing index.

Comment: I have a catch block at the end I just excluded it in the code I posted here.

Comment: It turns out if I remove the code for title partial match the response return the document as expected but as I add the title code the response returns an empty array

Comment: Can you add your database structure as screenshot?